# How to check logs of jenkins slave node

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

we had triggered the build job on Jenkins slave node which almost took 12+ hours to complete, which used to be completed within 4-5 hours. After that, I triggered one more job which was completed within 4-5 hours. Now, I want to figure out why the first job took longer to complete. As per suggestions, I tried to check /var/log/Jenkins and /etc/default, but nothing is configured over there. Is there any way to check the logs of a slave node, so I can figure out the issue with the first build. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using shared Library? What about  the console output ?

Comment: No, we aren't using Jenkins's shared library. It's a freestyle job. Console output is not showing anything abnormal, it's the same as the previous build.

Comment: @Chaitali please let me know if you have found answers for the question